# Automatically get (ymin,ymax) and (xmin,xmax) in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am plotting some 2D data from a file using pgfplots. Is it possible to automatically get (ymin,ymax) and (xmin,xmax) from the file I am trying to plot? I don't want to keep changing these each time I plot a different file.

Not setting these ranges will leave some undesired white spaces in my plots.

Comment: See [Christians answer](http://pgfplots-features.706524.n3.nabble.com/Pgfplots-features-Simple-calculations-on-columns-of-data-tp3851290p3873961.html) about calculations on data columns using the features of pgfplots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To prevent PGFPlots from adding padding around your data, set `enlargelimits=false`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
Default settings:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {
3 2
5 3
9 11
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\hspace{2cm}


With \verb|enlargelimits=false|:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
\addplot table {
3 2
5 3
9 11
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```